# unable to load json file into webgl code using request.open("GET", "cube.json");

Tags: javascript, ajax, webgl

I was experimenting with the code provided in http://www.learningwebgl.com and i was specifically trying to load a json image that resides in the same directory as my html file, but it is not getting loaded,

the code is :-

http://www.pasteall.org/23783

In http://www.learningwebgl.com i took the code that loaded a Teapot from lesson 14 and used it in Lesson 1. 
I am starting to think the problem maybe that I am drawing the object even before the file is loaded.

When i tried to debug using firebug am getting an error saying that my variable that is supposed to hold the vertex positions of the cube that i am loading is not defined

I am not an expert so debugging is bugging me.

Waiting for an answer

Thanks

Comment: Can someone help me with this?

Comment: See also http://groups.google.com/group/webgl-dev-list/browse_thread/thread/bb819427df322e36

Answer (score 1):

Your problem sounds like it is due to the fact that `XMLHttpRequest` is asynchronous (i.e. `request.send()` initiates a read, but does not wait for it to finish).

Try making the json load synchronous by changing the line

```
    request.open("GET", "cube.json");
```

to

```
    request.open("GET", "cube.json", false);
```

You can find the documentation for `XMLHttpRequest` at http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/